# How to remove the last comma in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Below is my script and I want to pass the value if not null to my `$weekDays`  variable in comma separated format but I want to remove the last comma, so please help me on this.

```
$a = "sun"
$b = "mon"
$c = $null
$d = $a,$b,$c
$weekDays = $null

Foreach ($i in $d)
{
 if ($i)
  {
    $weekDays = $i 
    $weekDays = $weekDays + ","
    Write-Host "$weekDays"
  }
}
```

Output: `sun,mon,`

I want: `sun, mon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = "sun"
$b = "mon"
$c = $null
$d = $a,$b,$c
$weekDays = $null

Foreach ($i in $d)
{
 if ($i)
  {
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($weekDays)))
    {
        $weekDays += ","
    }
    $weekDays = $weekDays + $i
  }
}
Write-Host "$weekDays"
##Output : sun,mon, I want : sun, mon
```

Your variable is null at start and you want to prepend a comma in all subsequent cases, that is, when the variable is no longer null.

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop through the list yourself since there's already the [`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.1) for that purpose, but you need to remove the null elements first

```
($d | Where-Object { $_ -ne $null }) -join ", "
```

[`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1) (alias `where`) will filter out the null elements.
If you just want to exclude the last null item then use this

```
$d[0..($d.Length - 2)] -join ", "
```

---

Note that your code produces the below output

```
sun,
mon,
```

and **not** `sun,mon,` in the same line. To print with new lines like that you need to use

```
($d | where { $_ -ne $null }) -join ",`n"
```